# Click on React list of elements and store it as a value in another list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, gatsby

I have this sample code which is a search input that filters and returns different colors in a list. When you click on one of the items the innerHTML from that list item then populates the value in the input field.

My question is when I click on one of the list items, I would want to get that specific list item and store it in another list. Much like a search history. Is this difficult to add to the current state of the search field? How would you suggest that I'd approach this?

Do i need to have some kind of onSubmit function to achieve this?

See this example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-6lkgu

Thanks beforehand,
Erik

Comment: Why not create a set called 'searchHistory' and anytime you click on an item you add it to 'searchHistory'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create an array in your state and push each option into it inside your `onClick` handler.  I made a simple example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-qii3h) that just logs the history when it changes.  You can then use/display it any way you'd like.

Note that you'd also need to add similar functionality inside of your `onKeyDown` handler, as it appears you're also triggering a change with the enter key.  I updated the fork to include this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a state variable searchHistory, which can be array, and onClick of the item, you can do :

```
  onClick = e => {
    this.setState({
      activeSuggestion: 0,
      filteredSuggestions: [],
      showSuggestions: false,
      userInput: e.currentTarget.innerText,
      searchHistory: [...this.state.searchHistory, e.currentTarget.innerText],
    });
  };
```

Comment: Thanks you sir! This worked. I will look through both of your answers. All the best / Erik

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want all of the search items to be unique?  You can use a set for that.  Here is the code below for your `AutoComplete` component.

```
constructor
```

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeSuggestion: 0,
      filteredSuggestions: [],
      showSuggestions: false,
      userInput: "",
      searchHistory: new Set([])
    };
  }
```

`onClick`

```
  onClick = e => {
    const { searchHistory } = this.state;

    searchHistory.add(e.currentTarget.innerText);

    this.setState(
      {
        activeSuggestion: 0,
        filteredSuggestions: [],
        showSuggestions: false,
        userInput: e.currentTarget.innerText,
        searchHistory: [
          ...searchHistory,
          searchHistory
        ]
      },
      () => {
        console.log("[search history]", this.state.searchHistory);
      }
    );
  };
```